# node.js JSON/REST framework for a single-page application

Tags: rest, node.js, mongodb

I'm developing an application that consists of a 'fat' javascript client backed by a JSON/REST server for data access. The data is stored in mongodb but the system should be flexible enough to switch to a relational backend if required.

I started out with [pintura](https://github.com/kriszyp/pintura) as the server side framework but recently ran into some problems (specifically with the perstore/filestore). I noticed that one problem has even been reported (including a fix) over a month ago, but there has been no reply to it and the issue is still present.
There seems to be relatively low activity in this project so I was wondering if many people are actually using it, and how stable the framework is.

Does anybody here have experience with this framework or know of an alternative framework that has similar capabilities?

Comment: I feel that your question is a bit unclear. Are you wondering whether node.js is a safe platform to do REST? Is your concern that node won't be able to interface well with a relational DB when necessary? Are you looking for alternative frameworks to try instead of node? Please be more specific :)

Comment: The question is not about node.js itself. It's about which framework to use on top of node for a data driven application. My research turned up [Persevere](http://persvr.org) (pintura is part of that) as a perfect framework for this. My problem is that I'm not sure if I should pin my hopes on that since there hasn't been a lot of activity there lately.

Comment: So in the last line of your question, the "this framework" refers to **pintura**, NOT to node, and the "alternative frameworks" is referring to things built *on top of* node. Thanks for the clarification! I'm going to suggest you edit the question to clarify that, so others don't have to read the comments to know ;)

While I'm not terribly familiar with the space, I don't think you'd have too much trouble going with node straight-up. It seems like it does data-driven rest-ful json extremely well.

Answer (score 0):

I agree the project and the website/blog does not seem to be active, although the [perstore repository](https://github.com/persvr/perstore)  does have recent activity.  I'd contact the author there since your problem seems more related to that.

A search for REST on http://search.npmjs.org/ will show quite a few results, although I cannot recommend any from experience.